# Riak Search, problems with fields starting with "-"

Tags: scala, riak

There seems to be a bit of problem when doing riak search, using Java Riak Client,

```
val result = client.mapReduce(BUCKET_NAME, searchHead + ":" + userID)
        .addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), true)
        .execute
```

Here, the userID is a twitter ID is , and the problem is that userID="-xxxxxx", you can see there is a "-".

And for some reason, when fields start with "-", the search doesn't return any result.

I am using Riak Java Client 1.1.4, and Riak version is 1.3.1

Comment: In the query, doesn't a value starting with `-` indicate exclusion?  Does it behave differently if you escape the first character with `\\`

Comment: @joe Well, newbie to riak here and sorry for the late reply, I didn't know that `-` was used for exclusions. I haven't tried escaping the first character yet, could you please be a bit more specific about how to do so??

Comment: I'm suggesting prepend a backslash ` \ ` to the userID when it starts with a `-`